# Как установить новое соедение после неудачного соедениения в selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Есть следующий код:

```
try:
    FireFoxBrowsr.get(str(regions_array) + str(categories_list[a][0]) ) 
except Exception:
```

Мне нужно что-бы при возникновении ошибки при подключении  скрипт пытался установить новое соединение до тех пор пока у него это не получиться. Поиски в интернете ничего не дали

Answer (score 0):

Если в лоб, то я представляю общую логику как без/конечный while цикл со строкой continue в реакции на ошибку в блоке except и там же таймаутом на время ожидания следующей попытки)))

```
import time
while True:
    try:
        browser.get(url) 
    except Exception:
        time.sleep(60)
        continue
```

Но в таком случае здоровым шагом будет реакция именно на WebDriverException (внутрибраузерные ошибки сети), а не на все Except:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
while True: 
    try:
        browser.get(url)
    except WebDriverException:
        time.sleep(60)
        continue
    except Exception:
        break
```

Ну и как вариант) можно добавить принты в except блоки, что-бы понимать о чём всё-же ошибка (или простым as, или сделать traceback):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import traceback
while True: 
    try:
        browser.get(url)
    except WebDriverException as wde:
        print(wde)
        time.sleep(60)
        continue
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        break
```